# Problems deserializing Json from MusixMatch API?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to implement MusixMatch API, I must admit, when I debug I'm unable to see what's in the ObservableCollection after the API call because the debugger jumps to another thread (I have zero expertise in thread management), however I can see what's the from the API response, Visual Studio says is not Json formatted:

```
  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync($"https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/artist.search?format=jsonp&callback=callback&q_artist=queen&page=1&page_size=5&apikey={apikey}"); 
        RootObject testList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
        return testList;
```

I have a model with this structure:

```
public class Header
{
    public int status_code { get; set; }
    public double execute_time { get; set; }
    public int available { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistNameTranslation
{
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string translation { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistNameTranslationList
{
    public ArtistNameTranslation artist_name_translation { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistAliasList
{
    public string artist_alias { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistCredits
{
    public List<object> artist_list { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public int artist_id { get; set; }
    public string artist_name { get; set; }
    public List<ArtistNameTranslationList> artist_name_translation_list { get; set; }
    public string artist_comment { get; set; }
    public string artist_country { get; set; }
    public List<ArtistAliasList> artist_alias_list { get; set; }
    public int artist_rating { get; set; }
    public string artist_twitter_url { get; set; }
    public ArtistCredits artist_credits { get; set; }
    public int restricted { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_time { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistList
{
    public Artist artist { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    public List<ArtistList> artist_list { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public Header header { get; set; }
    public Body body { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Message message { get; set; }
}
```

}

As I said I was able to see what's in the response from the API, you can look at the complete response:

```
callback({"message":{"header":    {"status_code":200,"execute_time":0.043232917785645,"available":6936},"body":{"artist_list":[{"artist":{"artist_id":118,"artist_name":"Queen","artist_name_translation_list":[{"artist_name_translation":{"language":"JA","translation":"\u30af\u30a4\u30fc\u30f3"}}],"artist_comment":"","artist_country":"","artist_alias_list":[{"artist_alias":"\u30af\u30a4\u30fc\u30f3"},{"artist_alias":"Queen + Adam Lambert"}],"artist_rating":99,"artist_twitter_url":"","artist_credits":{"artist_list":[]},"restricted":0,"updated_time":"2015-12-16T15:50:53Z"}},{"artist":{"artist_id":13755603,"artist_name":"Queen with David Bowie","artist_name_translation_list":[{"artist_name_translation":{"language":"EN","translation":"Queen"}}],"artist_comment":"","artist_country":"","artist_alias_list":[{"artist_alias":"Queen"}],"artist_rating":38,"artist_twitter_url":"","artist_credits":{"artist_list":[{"artist":{"artist_id":118,"artist_name":"Queen","artist_name_translation_list":[{"artist_name_translation":{"language":"JA","translation":"\u30af\u30a4\u30fc\u30f3"}}],"artist_comment":"","artist_country":"","artist_alias_list":[{"artist_alias":"\u30af\u30a4\u30fc\u30f3"},{"artist_alias":"Queen + Adam Lambert"}],"artist_rating":99,"artist_twitter_url":"","artist_credits":{"artist_list":[]},"restricted":0,"updated_time":"2015-12-16T15:50:53Z"}},{"artist":{"artist_id":431,"artist_name":"David Bowie","artist_name_translation_list":[{"artist_name_translation":{"language":"JA","translation":"\u30c7\u30f4\u30a3\u30c3\u30c9\u30fb\u30dc\u30a6\u30a4"}}],"artist_comment":"","artist_country":"GB","artist_alias_list":[{"artist_alias":"\u30c7\u30f4\u30a3\u30c3\u30c9\u30fb\u30dc\u30a6\u30a4"},{"artist_alias":"David Robert Jones"},{"artist_alias":"David Jones"},{"artist_alias":"Ziggy Stardust"},{"artist_alias":"\ub370\uc774\ube44\ub4dc \ubcf4\uc704"},{"artist_alias":"\u0414\u044d\u0432\u0438\u0434 \u0411\u043e\u0443\u0438"},{"artist_alias":"Davis Bowie"},{"artist_alias":"Bowie"},{"artist_alias":"\u30c7\u30d3\u30c3\u30c9\u30fb\u30dc\u30a6\u30a4"},{"artist_alias":"David Bowie"},{"artist_alias":"Davie Bowie"},{"artist_alias":"The Thin White Duke"}],"artist_rating":85,"artist_twitter_url":"","artist_credits":{"artist_list":[]},"restricted":0,"updated_time":"2018-10-20T16:37:59Z"}}]},"restricted":0,"updated_time":"2015-12-01T18:35:35Z"}},{"artist":{"artist_id":17057,"artist_name":"Queen Latifah","artist_name_translation_list":[{"artist_name_translation":{"language":"JA","translation":"\u30af\u30a4\u30fc\u30f3\u30fb\u30e9\u30c6\u30a3\u30d5\u30a1"}}],"artist_comment":"","artist_country":"US","artist_alias_list":[{"artist_alias":"\u30af\u30a4\u30fc\u30f3\u30fb\u30e9\u30c6\u30a3\u30d5\u30a1"},{"artist_alias":"Queen Latifa"},{"artist_alias":"Dana Owens"}],"artist_rating":46,"artist_twitter_url":"","artist_credits":{"artist_list":[]},"restricted":0,"updated_time":"2013-11-05T11:25:25Z"}},{"artist":{"artist_id":7321,"artist_name":"Queens of the Stone Age","artist_name_translation_list":[{"artist_name_translation":{"language":"RU","translation":"Queens Of The Stone Age"}}],"artist_comment":"","artist_country":"US","artist_alias_list":[{"artist_alias":"\u30af\u30a4\u30fc\u30f3\u30ba\u30aa\u30d6\u30b6\u30b9\u30c8\u30fc\u30f3\u30a8\u30a4\u30b8"},{"artist_alias":"Queens Of The Stone Age"},{"artist_alias":"shiqishidaihuanghou"},{"artist_alias":"Queen Of Stoneage"},{"artist_alias":"Queens Of The Stoneage"},{"artist_alias":"QOTSA"}],"artist_rating":76,"artist_twitter_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/qotsa","artist_credits":{"artist_list":[]},"restricted":0,"updated_time":"2015-12-09T18:04:11Z"}},{"artist":{"artist_id":26029011,"artist_name":"\u5973\u738b\u8702","artist_name_translation_list":[{"artist_name_translation":{"language":"EN","translation":"Queen Bee"}}],"artist_comment":"","artist_country":"JP","artist_alias_list":[{"artist_alias":"Queen Bee"}],"artist_rating":48,"artist_twitter_url":"","artist_credits":{"artist_list":[]},"restricted":0,"updated_time":"2019-07-15T13:55:16Z"}}]}}});
```

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RH9qxrCfKOXdX16eKy74iWhtbnfT46mD/view?usp=sharing)

As I said, Visual Studio is telling me that the response is not in Json>

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MoZlKEIbh8Epp_CC9gukWYtMBwp5oXwy/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It seems like the response string contains "callback(...)", which indeed is not JSON. You might want to format the response string to cut out the characters wrapping the actual JSON before doing your deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are passing a parameter `format=jsonp` in the URL.  [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is a format where JSON data is wrapped in a callback function.  It is intended to be used from within `<script>` tags in HTML pages.  If you want plain JSON, try changing that parameter to `format=json` and removing the corresponding `callback` parameter. Or you could try removing both `format` and `callback` parameters, assuming that JSON is the default format.

If that doesn't work, then the other alternative is to strip off the `callback()` function wrapper from the response string prior to trying to parse it as JSON.  You can do that with a helper method like this:

```
public static string ExtractJson(string text)
{
    int i = text.IndexOf('(');
    int j = text.LastIndexOf(')');
    return i > -1 && j > i ? text.Substring(i + 1, j - i - 1) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code to:

```cs
var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync($"https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/artist.search?format=jsonp&callback=callback&q_artist=queen&page=1&page_size=5&apikey={apikey}"); 

var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

RootObject testList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(contents);

return testList;
```